# Entity Framework repostory pattern GetAll() too slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm using repository layer. My problem here is GetAll() method is too slow when join a table with large records. It is taking 40 seconds to run a simple query.

IGenericRepository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity>
{
    TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    TEntity Insert(TEntity entity);
    TEntity Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Save();
}
```

GenericRepository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private MyStoreContext _dbContext;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        _dbContext = new MyStoreContext ();
        DbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(predicate).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet.AsNoTracking();
    }

    public TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public TEntity Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        DbSet.Add(entity);
        Save();
        return entity;
    }

    public TEntity Update(TEntity obj)
    {
        DbSet.Attach(obj);
        _dbContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;

        Save();
        return obj;
    }

    public void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = DbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (_dbContext.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }

        DbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage); // you just put the log to know the errors
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
                _dbContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Linq:

```
var conceptosDetalle = from pf in _parFactfRepository.GetAll()
                               join inve in _inveRepository.GetAll() on pf.CVE_ART equals inve.CVE_ART
                               where inve.STATUS == "A" && pf.CVE_DOC == cveDoc
                               orderby inve.CTRL_ALM, inve.CVE_ART
                               select new MyViewModel()
                               {
                                   CTRL = inve.CTRL_ALM,
                                   CVE_ART = inve.CVE_ART,
                                   UNID = "PIEZA",
                                   CANT = pf.CANT,
                                   DESCR = inve.DESCR,
                                   PREC = pf.PREC,
                                   DESC1 = pf.DESC1,
                                   TOTIMP4 = pf.TOTIMP4
                               };
```

The query returns 10 records. parFactfRepository contains 992590 rows, inveRepository contains 41908 rows.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think this is going to download the entirety of those 2 tables and join them in memory, instead of on the database, due to `GetAll` being `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because you're mixing and matching repository-based queries and LINQ queries. Rather than doing a true join, you're fetching *all* the rows for each table and then joining them in-memory.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to just return `IQueryable<TEntity>` rather than `IEnumerable<TEntity>` from your `GetAll` method. Using `IEnumerable<TEntity>` forces the query to evaluate. If you're going to return `IEnumerable<TEntity>` your data should be fully-baked, i.e. no further alterations to the query are necessary (including joins).

That said, this is yet one more failing of trying to use the repository pattern with EF. If you aren't *very* careful, you end up introducing logical errors like this that aren't obvious as to why they are happening. Entity Framework *already* implements the repository pattern; *that is what a `DbSet` is*. If you want an abstraction over that, introduce a service layer. With that, you'd simply have a method like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewModel> GetConceptosDetalle()
{
    ...
}
```

And that method would contain this entire query (using EF directly, rather than your completely unnecessary repository layer). That way, your application simply calls a method that returns the data it needs, and that service layer contains all the logic. That's true abstraction. With a repository, you're bleeding logic all over your codebase.

*Note: I made it return `MyViewModel` simply for ease of explanation, but in reality, you should return some sort of DTO, which you could then map to your view model. It would be bad idea to leak view business logic into a service layer.*

Comment: Thank a lot for your advice. Now i'm working on it. +1

Comment: Upvoting this *so hard* because of the mini-rant against trying to wrap Entity Framework inside a repository / unit of work pattern. I've hard that conversation *twice* so far this week.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I don't need the upvote. There is simply no good reason to use the repository pattern with EF, or any ORM, period. The problem the repository pattern solves is solved by an ORM, which is why virtually every ORM I've seen implements the repository pattern. If your goal is to abstract EF, there's more appropriate ways, such as a service layer, as mentioned.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to express my agreement with you on that, since it feels like I need to explain this same thing to people weekly here at work.

Comment: @BradleyUffber: Oh, sorry, it seemed as if you were implying that that advice was wrong. Sarcasm is so hard to read online. I often have the same issue, being fairly sarcastic myself, by nature.

Comment: hi @ChrisPratt, can you add an url where it explains why repository pattern is a bad practice with EF

Comment: @Rolando: Well, not to be self-promotional, but there's this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126#220126 and https://cpratt.co/repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework/. I don't know off the top of my head anything else written by others, but I'm sure a simple Google search can surface a few.